# save initial state of array and reset in scala

Tags: scala

I am wondering what is the best way to save the initial state of an Array in scala so I can reset with initial values after manipulating a working copy. I would like to do something like this

```
val initialValue = Array(Array(1,2,3),Array(4,5,6))
val workingCopy = initialValue.clone
```

The problem is that when I change values of workingCopy, I also change the values of initialValue.

I also tried

```
val workingCopy = Array.fill(2,3)(0)
Array.copy(initialValue,0,workingCopy,2)
```

But I get the same result.

This holds even if i use `var` instead of `val` when defining the arrays. I think this shallow copy behavior might be caused by the nested Array structure, but I'm not sure how to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Angelo, you usually want to use immutable data structures to avoid problems like this. However, if you really need to go the mutable way, e.g. for performance reasons (although the "modification" of immutable collections, such as `Vector`, is not as expensive as you might think), then you need to do a *deep copy* of your nested arrays and the content. The implementation is up to you.

---

If it really is just an `Array[Array[Int]]`, it's enough to do something like this:

```
val initialValue = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6))
val workingCopy = initialValue.map(_.clone)
```

---

A more general example using a reference type instead of simple `Int`s:

```
scala> class Cell(var x: String) { def copy = new Cell(x); override def toString = x }
defined class Cell

scala> val initialValue = Array(Array(new Cell("foo")))
initialValue: Array[Array[Cell]] = Array(Array(foo))

scala> val workingCopy = initialValue.map(_.map(_.copy))
workingCopy: Array[Array[Cell]] = Array(Array(foo))

scala> initialValue(0)(0).x = "bar"
initialValue(0)(0).x: String = bar

scala> initialValue
res0: Array[Array[Cell]] = Array(Array(bar))

scala> workingCopy
res1: Array[Array[Cell]] = Array(Array(foo))
```

Instead of `initialValue.map(_.map(_.copy))`, there are of course other ways to do the same thing (e.g. a nested `for` expression which copies the objects as its side effect).

Answer (score 0):

`var` vs `val` really just determines whether the reference is immutable, it would have no effect on the contents of the data structure. if you were to convert to an immutable data structure, for example a `List`, then the copy would be unneeded as the operations for "modifying" the contents of such a structure create a new reference leaving the original untouched.

for example:

```
val initialValue = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))

val sumInnerLists = initialValue.map(l => l.foldLeft(0)(_ + _))

println(sumInnerLists) // List(6, 15)
println(initialValue)  // List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6))
```

Comment: I realize that most of the time, you want to use immutable data structures. However, my data is a really large matrix which I want to call a recursive function on, and I don't want to create a new object every time I recursively call the function or pass the argument to it every time (it's much less expensive to modify in place).

Comment: In that case, you could make initial value an immutable list, and convert to an array (or other mutable structure) to get your working copy.